# Number of invertible symmetric $3\times 3$ matrices over a finite field $F =\mathbb{F}_q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, finite-groups, finite-fields

I was trying to find the number of symmetric invertible matrices of size $n\times n$ over a finite field $F= \mathbb{F}_q$ ( $q$ odd for simplicity)

For $n=2$ it has to do with counting the number of zeroes of a quadratic form over a finite field, something that was seen before on this site.

For $n = 3$ it is a completely new problem.

I am trying it in this way:

The first subset of (symmetric) invertible matrices are the one having a Gauss decomposition

$$A = L D U$$

where $L$ is lower triangular unipotent, $U$ is upper triangular unipotent, and $D$ is diagonal with non-zero diagonal values. If $A$ is moreover symmetric then $L = U^t$.  Now the number of such matrices is simple to determine. The  matrices with  a [Gauss decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition) are those for which $D_1$, $\ldots$, $D_n \ne 0$. where $D_k$ are the leading minors, $1\le k \le n$. So we got a subset of the set of symmetric invertible matrices.

Let's try to determine the number of $n\times n$ symmetric invertible matrices. Now, let $d_{n-1}$ the number of symmetric $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ matrices that are invertible.  From this we can complete the off diagonal elements in $q^{n-1}$ ways, and the last diagonal element in $(q-1)$ ways ( use the [Cauchy formula for expanding the determinant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CauchysDeterminantTheorem.html)).

The problem is what happens if the $D_{n-1}$ leading minor is in fact zero. Now its rank starts to matter.  Perhaps I could cover the case $n=3$, but it looks a bit confusing.

Notes: I am aware there exists a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.5440) that solves this problem ( symmetric matrices with $0$ determinant over the ring $\mathbb{Z}_m$), but it seems hard to read.   Even inequalities would be helpful.

Any feedback would be welcome!

Comment: The linked paper only seems to address the question directly for the case that $q$ is itself prime, since $\Bbb Z_{p^a} \not\cong \Bbb F_{p^a}$ for $p$ prime and $a > 1$. Of course, the case that $q$ is prime is already interesting.

Comment: The case that $q$ is prime (in the linked paper's notation, $\mu = 1$) seems to be resolved in Carlitz, L. Representations by quadratic forms in a finite field. *Duke Mathematical Journal*, **21**(1) (1954), 123–137. doi:10.1215/s0012-7094-54-02114-6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked paper only seems to address the question directly for the case that $q$ is itself prime (in the notation of that reference, $\mu = 1$), since $\Bbb Z_{p^a} \not\cong \Bbb F_{p^a}$ for $p$ prime and $a > 1$.

In any case, the linked paper's formula simplifies substantially in the case that $q$ is prime (which we'll assume herein, as well as that $q > 2$), and in fact that case was resolved a few decades earlier in:

> Carlitz, L. Representations by quadratic forms in a finite field. *Duke Math. J.* (1954) **21**(1), 123–137. doi:10.1215/s0012-7094-54-02114-6

In particular, the coefficients $T_\beta(k, s) = T_\beta(k, 0)$ in the linked paper of Brent & McKay are identically $1$, as is the leading coefficient of equation (5.2) there. That equation gives the proportion $P(n, q)$ of symmetric $n \times n$ matrices over $\Bbb F_q$ that are nondegenerate, and there are $q^{{n + 1} \choose 2}$ symmetric matrices, so multiplying gives a general formula for the count $q^{{n + 1} \choose 2} P(n, q)$ that depends on the parity of $n$. (Unfortunately, the linked paper instead denotes the prime by $p$ and defines $q = \frac{1}{p}$. The below formulae are instead consistent with the question statement.)

- If $n$ is even there are
  $$q^{{n + 1} \choose 2} \frac{\prod_{j = 1}^n (1 - q^{-j})}{\prod_{j = 1}^{n / 2} (1 - q^{-2 j})}$$ invertible, symmetric matrices over $\Bbb F_q$.
- If $n$ is odd there are
  $$q^{{n + 1} \choose 2} (1 - q^{-n}) \frac{\prod_{j = 1}^{n - 1} (1 - q^{-j})}{\prod_{j = 1}^{(n - 1) / 2} (1 - q^{-2 j})} $$
  invertible, symmetric matrices over $\Bbb F_q$.

In the special case that $n = 3$, there are
$$(q^3 - 1) (q^3 - q^2) = q^6 - q^5 - q^3 + q^2$$
invertible, symmetric matrices over $\Bbb F_q$. A quick Maple script verifies this formula for $q = 3, 5, 7$. (This count is $\frac{1}{q^3 - q}$ times the number of invertible $3 \times 3$ matrices---not necessarily symmetric---over $\Bbb F_q$, and some meditation on that fact might suggest a slick way to produce the above formula.)

Comment: Thank you! Great answer ! (still digesting it...)

Comment: After looking at Carlitz's paper, I wonder if we can proceed like this:  there are two types of non-deg quadratic forms ( over finite $F$ odd char) depending on $\det Q$  being a square or not.  Since $GL(n, F)$ acts transitively on each orbit, we only need the cardinality of the stabilizer, which is an orthogonal group.  It seems in odd dim both of the groups are in fact iso. Maybe that is the reason for the formula for $n = 3$.  So understanding orthogonal groups over finite fields is key here. Wonder if there is another slicker way to see it for $n=3$.

Comment: That seems to be right. For odd $n$, $O(2 n + 1, q) = 2 q^{n^2} \prod_{i = 1}^n (q^{2 i} - 1)$. For $O(3, q)$, i.e., $n = 1$, the formula simplifies to $2 (q^3 - q)$, which gives that each orbit has size $|GL(3, q) / |O(3, q)| = (q^3 - 1)(q^3 - q)(q^3 - q^2) / 2 (q^3 - q) = \frac{1}{2} (q^3 - 1) (q^3 - q^2)$. There are two orbits, thus giving a total count $(q^3 - 1) (q^3 - q^2)$ elements as expected. All of the above works for general prime powers $q > 1$, not just primes, so that formula works in that case too.

Comment: So, for odd $n$, the total number of nondegenerate $n \times n$ symmetric matrices over $\Bbb F_q$ looks like $q^{\frac{1}{4}(n^2 - 1)} (q^n - 1) (q^{n - 2} - 1) \cdots (q - 1)$. The even case should be similar, except that, like you wrote, the two orbits have different sizes.

Comment: In any case, perhaps consider writing up outlining the orbit-stabilizer argument and (since it also covers the case that $q$ is not prime) accept it? If you'd rather not, I'm happy to update my answer to include it.

Comment: It would be great if you could sketch the cardinality of the orthogonal group(s) ( and maybe the reason they are iso if $n$ odd). Greatly appreciated!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147445/discussion-between-orangeskid-and-travis-willse).